# How to compare the difference between two periods of time using DateTime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, logic

I have a class that has two datetimes (Begin and End) and a flag (Primal) who must be unique 'true' for that period.

```
public class ClassTest
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Primal { get; set; }
    public DateTime Begin { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> End { get; set; }
}
```

If there's a ClassTest populated with 'Description' = "Whatever" 'Primal' = true, 'begin' = 06/12/2013 and 'End' = 10/12/2013, and i try to insert another object with 'Primal' = true, 'begin' = 05/12/2013 and 'End' = null, the application must return (via link on a class that validate that theresn't any other object 'primal' on period that i'm trying to insert) that already's a object on the period of the second object.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Where would you insert the `ClassTest` object? Could you give us sample input and expected results?

Comment: You can compare DateTimes, just like you do it with any other type. Do the rest of the logic any way you want. No, there's no magical function to do exactly what you want.

Comment: It's extremely unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Your updated question makes it pretty clear this has nothing to do with DateTimes. You just want to go through all the items in your collection, compare their respective Begin and End dates and do your validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static bool IsValid(ClassTest current, ClassTest other)
{
    if (!other.Primal || !current.Primal)
        return true;
    if (current.End.HasValue 
        && other.End.HasValue
        && (other.End.Value <= current.Begin || other.Begin >= current.End.Value))
        return true;
    if (!current.End.HasValue 
        && other.End.HasValue
        && other.End.Value <= current.Begin)
        return true;
    if (current.End.HasValue 
        && !other.End.HasValue
        && other.Begin >= current.End.Value)
        return true;

    return false;
}

var isUnique = existing.All(item => IsValid(item, newItem));
```